# set the <div> back to the values before page loading

Tags: html

i have the following html code with a dropdown-toggle

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="box collapsed-box">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
      <div class="box-tools pull-right">
        <button data-widget="collapse" class="btn btn-box-tool"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-box-tool dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></button>
        </div>
        <button data-widget="remove" class="btn btn-box-tool"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body" style="display: none;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="chart-responsive">
            <canvas height="200" id="salesChart" style="width: 675px; height: 200px;" width="675"></canvas>
            <a href="page2.php">page 2</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can open and close the dropdown-toogle.

after clicking on a href-link and a full page refresh the dropdown-toogle should be opened/closed as it was before.

1) how can i get the right values of the divs?
e.g,.  when it is closed and  when it is opened

2) how can i set the status of the dropdown-toogle back to the one before the page was refreshed?

Comment: What happens in PHP on the refresh?

Comment: for example:
1) dropdown-toogle closed  with <div class="box collapsed-box">
2) switch to open <div class="box">
3) the page is loaded in the old status again with closed dropdown-toogle

Comment: What href link? And perhaps use a cookie?

Comment: a href inside the page, e.g., <a href="page2.php">page 2</a>

Comment: using a cookie is one way but how can i extract/get the values inside the <div> before loading the site again